# apache cxf - convert WSDL to Java

Tags: java, wsdl, cxf, converters

I need convert WSDL to Java. I run command line with command `wsdl2java SERVICE.WSDL` but it resulted in error:

> "the system cannot find the path specified"

anyone help me?

Comment: It is not the tool which is emitting this error, but your operating system trying to tell you that it cannot find one of the paths you told it to find. Please double-check how you invoke the generator, and maybe give more details, like the exact command line and the very exact error message (how about a screenshot of the terminal window with the call and the error side by side?)

Comment: I can't put the screenshot, i need 10 reputation . But I use WSDL2JAVA GetService.wsdl command and resulted in error: the system cannot find the path specified. I didn't set environment variables.

Comment: Add the commands (text not screen shot) to the post.

Comment: The only command that I used is :

wsdl2java GetService.wsdl

The wsdl2java is a batch file and it is the bin folder of apache cxf.

Comment: So the wsdl is located in the same folder like the wsdl2java batch? Does not feel right. Are you sure about the exact command line? If I had to guess, I'd say you either forgot to qualify the path to the wsdl or called the generator from a place where it is not visible, or both. As for the screenshots, you can upload them to some image sharing site like imgur and post a link to the upload in your question. Higher-rep users may include it for you.

Answer (score 3):

According to batch:

```
@echo off
rem
rem
rem    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
rem    or more contributor license agreements. See the NOTICE file
rem    distributed with this work for additional information
rem    regarding copyright ownership. The ASF licenses this file
rem    to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
rem    "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
rem    with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
rem
rem    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
rem
rem    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
rem    software distributed under the License is distributed on an
rem    "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
rem    KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the
rem    specific language governing permissions and limitations
rem    under the License.
rem
rem

rem 
rem  invoke the Apache CXF wsdl2java tool
rem 
@setlocal

if not defined CXF_HOME goto set_cxf_home

:cont
if not defined JAVA_HOME goto no_java_home

set TOOLS_JAR=%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar;

if not exist "%CXF_HOME%\lib\cxf-manifest.jar" goto no_cxf_jar

set CXF_JAR=%CXF_HOME%\lib\cxf-manifest.jar


"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -Xmx128M -Djava.endorsed.dirs="%CXF_HOME%\lib\endorsed" -cp "%CXF_JAR%;%TOOLS_JAR%;%CLASSPATH%" -Djava.util.logging.config.file="%CXF_HOME%\etc\logging.properties" org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava %*

@endlocal

goto end

:no_cxf_jar
echo ERROR: Unable to find cxf-manifest.jar in %cxf_home/lib
goto end

:no_java_home
echo ERROR: Set JAVA_HOME to the path where the JDK (6.0 or higher) is installed
goto end 

:set_cxf_home
set CXF_HOME=%~dp0..
goto cont

:end
```

According to me, there can be just one problem, which can generate error you reported.
Path **%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar** doesn't exist. 
So, please check if enviroment variable JAVA_HOME exists and if it is correctly set.

Comment: i had same problem. In my case, i put a semicolon ";" at the end of `%JAVAHOME%` environment variable that need to be **removed**.